# How can I send an email alert every day to 5000 contacts

Tags: batch, email-template, email-alert, time-dependent-workflow, singleemailmessage

We want to send an email to contacts every day.  There will be say 5000 contacts.  I can't do this with apex code because there is a limit of 500 emails per 24 hour period.  So I will have to do this with a workflow rule, workflow email alert and email template.

Option 1 is to create an apex batch job to update contacts every day and this update would fire the workflow email alert.  The workflow would probably need to reset a flag when it fires and the apex job could would set it again and so on.

Option 2 is to use a time dependant workflow. The workflow would create a future update of the contact in 24 hours and send an email alert now.  I may need a second workflow to fire when the first workflow does the update.  This second workflow would do an update to fire the first workflow again and so on and so on....

With Option 2 there is a limit of 1000 time dependant rules per hour per org so this would take 5 hours to complete.

With Option 1 are there any limts to the number of workflow rules a batch process can fire or casue to fire which I need to be aware of?

Limits I know of:

1000 workflow emails per user per day.  We have 30 standard users and 100 community users.

1000 time dependant workflows per hour per org.

500 single email messages from APEX code to contacts per 24 hour period.

1000 mass email messagas form APEX code per 24 hour period.

Thanks

Carlo

Comment: What about using lets say 10 emails that have 500 BCC addresses on it, sent via apex?

Comment: Ha Ha nice try.  No the limit is per email address I believe.  Also we want to send a different email to each contact.  So each email will be different.

Comment: You need to integrate Salesforce with either ExactTarget or dotMailer to send large amount of emails.

Comment: I've decided to go with Option 1.  I created a test scenario in my Production Org.  I setup a workflow rule to send 2 emails and update a checkbox on Contact record when some condition is met.  I then inserted 1200 Contacts via Dataloader with email address = mine.  I then sat back and watched my Outlook grind to a halt as the 2400 emails arrived slowly.  It took about 30 mins in total for all the emails to arrive. The Dataloader job completed much much sooner.

Answer (score 1):

Third Party mass Email application would be a great solution for sending Mass Emails as  there are limitations in salesforce in sending Mass Emails i.e. 250 emails in Professional Edition, 500 in Enterprise Edition and 1000 in Unlimited Edition.

In order to make yourself Unlimited while sending the mass emails to Contacts, Leads, Users and sending emails Campaign Members then you need to check an appexchange native app - MassMailer.This will let you bypass salesforce mass email limits, let you choose sender email address, reply to email address and at the same time let you send simple marketing emails to Schedule one-off mass emails. With this you can keep tack of you Emails i.e. it got delivered, Opened, Unsubscribed etc.

For this, you might need to visit and play with this app -

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000005uxj5EAA

Comment: I see this is an unlisted app. Do you have any association with them?

Comment: We are the originator and developer off this App.

Comment: Thank you. Its always wise to divulge any association one has with an app when making recommendations to avoid the appearance of inappropriately promoting a product for personal gain.